# Has the pronunciation of "que" changed in Quebec?

Tags: prononciation

(Sorry, I don't know how to represent or read sounds phonetically.) I left Quebec 35 years ago. Now when I listen to Quebec radio, I'm surprised to often hear the vowel in *que* pronounced like the *i* in the English *fit*. The only pronunciation I heard previously was this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8S0cXeCeSd0 (although the two speakers sound very slightly different to me). Is this change my imagination? If not, what's the cause?

Comment: The *I* in *fit* is a near-close near-front unrounded vowel and is represented by this character: [ɪ] while the *E* in *que* is a mid central vowel or schwa: [ə]. See this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA_vowel_chart_with_audio).